# How to draw MS Paint like (aliased), 1px circle in GIMP

Tags: gimp, pixel-art

I was trying to draw some pixel are amd first thing is to try a circle via stroke path with miter set to 0, anti-alias off, 1 px line.
Here is what I get in Gimp. Part of the circle are ok, others are not (red arrow points to them). Any suggestions? Thanks.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you can get slightly better results by stroking the path with the [pencil tool](http://docs.gimp.org/en/gimp-tool-pencil.html), using a single-pixel brush:

[image: Pixelated circles drawn with pencil tool in GIMP]

They're still not quite as nice and symmetrical as the pixel art circles produced by the [Bresenham circle algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Midpoint_circle_algorithm) used in MS paint, but at least they're a little bit closer.

Comment: Hm, I guess I missed that option. Thanks. It seems I'm gonna turn to Paint.NET or other programs, made for pixel art (didn't succeed with photoshop either).

Comment: @Ilmari Karonen How do you know Bresenham circle algorithm is used in MS paint? I ask because I need to know which algorithm they use, and wanted to check that you are positive they use that.

Comment: @Santropedro: I _don't_ know for sure, but it _looks_ like what Bresenham's algorithm would produce, and it's sort of the obvious choice anyway. Especially given how old MS Paint originally is. Back in the day, Bresenham's algorithm (specifically the integer-only form) would be what you'd use if you needed to draw a circle on a computer.